# TextEditor Keyboard Avoidance

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I shift the view upwards with `TextEditor`? When I use a `TextField` object, I have no problems with it, because keyboard avoidance is now provided by default. However, if I use a `TextEditor`, my view does not even react to the keyboard like `TextField` does.

I tried [this solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65030757/avoiding-keyboard-in-swifui-with-texteditor), but it did not fix my view.

Comment: Did you find any solution? Could you share it here?